# Help with understanding the definition of operation

Tags: logic, notation, terminology, definition

I'm having trouble understanding this excerpt from Wikipedia, which defines an **operation**:

[image]

Mainly, I don't understand what is meant by $V \subset X_1 \times...\times X_k$. Why does an operation have *multiple* domains? I thought there was just one domain and one codomain.

Can you please explain the whole passage in easier terms, the notation is kind of confusing and I'm new to mathematical formalism. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the binary operation $F(x,n)=x^n$, where $x\in\Bbb R$ and $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $F$ has the domain $\Bbb{R\times N}$ and codomain $\Bbb R$.

The reason to allow multiple domains is just to make it easier than to require, each time, that the domain is the union of $X_1\cup\ldots\cup X_k$. I don't know where the text is from, or where it is going to [mathematically], but I can see why this might be an easier set up than requiring one domain and keeping track of it all the time.

Comment: Ok, thanks +1. But $R \times N$ is really one domain, right? because natural numbers are a subset of the reals, so wouldn't that count as one domain?

Comment: Yes, as a function there is just one domain. But sometimes you benefit from understanding a bit more how the domain looks like, and what sort of sets include each of its projections.

Comment: @user437158, even if $\mathbb{N}$ were not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, there would still be just one domain - the set $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$ - which would be a single set even if $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ were *disjoint*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I think that also in some formal contexts, it becomes essential to see functions as having multiple domains.  If, for instance, you want to study the model theory of vector spaces without specifying a base field, your language structure needs to have two universes.  I don't know if this something anybody studies much, though...

Answer (score 1):

$k$ given in the article varies. For example ordinary addition of natural numbers $+$ is an operation that is binary and for that $k=2$ because you take $n,m$ and then apply $+$ to get $n+m$...similarly taking modulus is an unary operation as for that $k=1$ as you take $x$ and have $|x|$...thus your $k$ depends on the operation you are defining.